# What's wrong with my .bat script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, 7zip

So, I am trying to write a script that uses 7-zip to extract a .zip file *containing another .zip file* into the current directory and delete it.

Everything works fine when I type it into the command prompt:

```
set 7ZIP="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe"
for %X in (*.zip) do start "Extracting..." /WAIT %7ZIP% x "%X" && del "%X"
```

However, when I try to do this in a .bat file (note the %%), I get a strange error

```
set 7ZIP="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe"
for %%X in (*.zip) do start "Extracting..." /WAIT %7ZIP% x "%%X" && del "%%X"
```

[image: Failed]

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like `/WAIT ZIPX` in the screenshot but `/WAIT %7ZIP%` in what's typed here -- did you re-type the content here or is that a copy-and-paste from your actual batch file?

Comment: No, I just double-clicked my .bat file and this is what came up. It's strange, huh?

Comment: Very. At least you figured out the probable cause...

Comment: I would download a different shell. cmd is abandon-ware, microsoft never finished it.

Comment: Mmmm... I think it is time to install Cygwin.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I just learned that you apparently can't have variables starting with numbers in .bat scripts (or the start command??), because this works:

```
set ZIP7="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe"
for %%X in (*.zip) do start "Extracting..." /WAIT %ZIP7% x "%%X" && del "%%X"
```

Comment: Yes - batch sees the `%7` in `%7ZIP%` and assumes you are trying to access the 7th command line parameter. It is interesting that it works if you enable delayed expansion and use !7ZIP! instead. But it is still a good idea to never create environment variables that begin with a number.